# How do I install a font on a user's machine in VB.NET so applications like Word can use it?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, fonts

Need to install a font on all user's machines that will use the application I am writing which creates custom documents in Word.  It's a barcode font.

I've successfully added the font to my solution and set its build action to Embedded Resource and have also successfully written code to check if the font is already installed on the user's system.

Now I just need to figure out how to extract the font from my solution and install it onto the user's machine as if they installed the font themselves for use in Office applications, etc.

Most of the examples I've found out there are for using the font within the VB.NET application instead of outside it and the one's I have found which seem to fit my purpose aren't working for me.

Comment: Just to comment that you need to ensure that you are allowed to distribute the font - fonts are software just like your program and you need permission before distributing one the way you describe.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that is typically (and best) done by an *installer*, rather than your program itself. It's usually easier to tell your setup program to install a font than it is to do it from within your application.

Comment: That would be great but I assume that's not something that coupd be done with the ClickOnce installer that comes with Visual Studio 2010 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the font into the Windows font folder and then you need to get the font added to the registry. I've not tried this myself, but I think it's possible to do this by opening the font using the `ShellExecuteA` api in a similar way to as seen [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918).

Here's a vbscript way of doing it that might be useful as a starting point since you might be able to use similar syntax and functions in VB.Net: [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Install Fonts Using a Script?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/25/how-can-i-install-fonts-using-a-script.aspx)

Comment: Why would you use the non-Unicode version of `ShellExecute`? And how exactly does that add the font to the Registry? I don't see that given as an example in the link you provided.

Comment: This is actually the easiest solution.  This method's behavior is as if you double-click the font in Windows which if you don't mind a pop-up install progress bar from Windows is not bad at all.  Check if font exists, if not, copy resource to wherever, run shellexecute and then delete the font file extracted.

Comment: Still, you should definitely be using the Unicode version of `ShellExecute`. And I don't believe that this informs running applications that the system font table has been modified; if it's possible Word could be running *while* your application is installing fonts, this is something to keep in mind.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the Unicode version of ShellExecute?

Comment: @Tom: A W instead of an A. If you use the standard .NET P/Invoke syntax, you won't have a problem. But if you try and copy-paste VBScript samples into VB.NET, you'll end up with a mess (for oh so many reasons!).

Comment: Cody, here's the code I used...didn't even use shellexecute:         Dim objFileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        On Error Resume Next

        objFileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(gsBarCodeFontFile)
        objFileInfo.CopyTo("C:\" & gsBarCodeFontFile)
        Dim objFolder = objShell.Namespace(&H14&)
        objFolder.CopyHere("C:\" & gsBarCodeFontFile)
        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\" & gsBarCodeFontFile)

Comment: @Tom: Yeah... Unfortunately, it doesn't *just* look terrible because of Stack Overflow's formatting. That's mostly VBScript code, which you **really** should not be writing in VB.Net, even if it compiles. Lots of things are supported for backwards compatibility, but are a really bad idea. Untyped objects are a good example. Also, I don't even think that mess *would* compile if you were working with Option Strict and Option Explicit both on like you should be.

Comment: @ho1: In the future, please try to make clear that the VBScript is strictly a sample on the algorithms/functions needed, etc. rather than something directly useful in VB.Net. Let's not perpetuate this misguided notion that VB is awful because we teach people to write bad code in it. I'm not doenvoting, because everything you said is strictly correct, but I'm a little tempted because this just reeks of bad advice to an inexperienced developer. Just something to consider. :-)

Comment: @Tom: I agree with Cody that you should have `Option Explicit` on so that you have to declare the type of `objFolder`. Also, I'd look at using `IO.Path.Combine` instead of `&` to add the paths together.

Comment: @Cody: Well, I normally try to avoid `CreateObject` and similar, but if I needed to do this I might be tempted to since it seems like a reasonably neat solution which in some ways makes up for the ugliness of the `CreateObject`. Though I agree that the wording of my answer wasn't (And still isn't) that good.

Answer (score 11):

First, you need to copy the font to the Windows\Fonts directory (you'll want to make sure to use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method provided by the .NET Framework instead of hard-coding the typical path to the Windows directory, just in case something is different in one of your users' environments).

Then, you need to call the [`AddFontResource` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326.aspx) to add the font to the system font table. Since `AddFontResource` is provided by the Windows API, you'll need to P/Invoke to call it from VB.NET code. The declaration looks something like this (the `lpszFilename` parameter is the path to the font file that you want to add):

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll"), CharSet := CharSet.Auto> _
Public Shared Function AddFontResource(ByVal lpszFilename As String) As Integer
```

Finally, if Word (or whatever application you intend to use the font in) is *running* at the time you call the `AddFontResource` function from your code, you need to inform it that the available fonts have changed. You do this by sending a `WM_FONTCHANGE` message to all top-level windows using the `SendMessage` function and setting the `hWnd` parameter to`HWND_BROADCAST`. Again, you'll need to P/Invoke; the declarations look like this:

```
Public Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
Public Const WM_FONTCHANGE As Integer = &H1D

<DllImport("user32.dll"), CharSet := CharSet.Auto> _
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
```

And you would call it to send the broadcast message like this:

```
SendMessage(New IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```

**NOTE:** The above steps only install the font for the current Windows session. If you need the font to be available on subsequent restarts, you need to add it to the registry. The key to modify is this one:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

Comment: I was just going to ask how to get the user's font directory, thanks, but there is no property for the fonts folder using this method: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.[Fonts]).  Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, you're right that `Environment.SpecialFolder` doesn't expose the fonts folder. Here's an explanation of how you get at it the *right* way in .NET: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2008/08/25/getting-the-fonts-folder.aspx (No, you don't just add "`\FONTS`" to the path returned by `SpecialFolder.System`.)

Comment: The MSDN documentation is pretty confusing. [The font installation topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833.aspx) says copying the font file to Windows\Fonts then calling AddFontResource **will** install the font permanently, but the [AddFontResource page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326.aspx) says the font must be listed in the registry

Comment: @MarkJ: Yeah that's not unusual for MSDN. But this catches my eye on your first link: "To temporarily install a font, call AddFontResource or AddFontResourceEx. These functions load a font that is stored in a font-resource file. However, this is a temporary installation because after a reboot the font will not be present." I suppose the only way go be truly sure is to test it, and I haven't.

Answer (score 3):

First you copy the font to the windows font folder then call [AddFontResource](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/AddFontResource.html) using p/invoke.

Here is an example, it's in C# but you should be able to work it out:

**UPDATE**

New URL

http://brutaldev.com/post/2009/03/26/Installing-and-removing-fonts-using-C.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that this will work, in the docs for AddFontResource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)it says *This function installs the font only for the current session. When the system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in the registry.*

Comment: To be available after restarting the maching you'll need to change the appropriate registry entry in that case, (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts)

Answer (score 0):

I used the installer project to install the fonts I needed with my application and followed this [guide](http://jgvimalan.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/installing-font-using-c-setup-project/)